# Reporting error in publication after copyright transfer

Tags: copyright, errors-erratum

Last year my paper got accepted in a Mathematics journal. This year the online first version of the article came out. I put the online version on research gate and a lot of people read the article. Then a fellow reader pointed out a big mistake in last part of the paper.
I mailed and informed the journal regarding the error.I told them the error does not seem to be fixable at the moment and requested them if they could update the paper by removing the erroneous part.  After a week I noticed that the journal has taken down the online first version from their website. But till now I haven’t received a reply to my mail. It has been a month now.

Can anyone tell what I should do now? I mailed the journal secretary yesterday, but no response.

I should also mention that I had submitted the copyright transfer form , after proof reading i.e Just before the online first version came out.
Also the journal is a decent one with .50 MCQ on mathscinet.

Well I expect a response from them because then I would know what their plan is with my paper, so that without loosing time I can publish it somewhere else if required.

Comment: What do you expect? You reported an error (and probably asked to take it down?), they took it down.  What do you expect them to do? Wouldn't it be on you to follow up?

Comment: It is my work in the first place and I expect that they at least inform me about their plan with my paper. Or tell me if I can try publishing my paper somewhere else.

Comment: But what *did* you write them?

Comment: In the first mail where I informed about the error, I also mentioned that the error does not seem to be fixable at present. Since I did not get any reply since then, I mailed the secretary yesterday asking if I can get a update on the status of the paper.

Comment: Well, if there is a non-fixable error, it is not unlikely they withdrew it?  Or they are waiting for you to update them on whether you were able to fix it or not?  --  I'm just not sure why you expect *they* should get back to *you*?

Comment: I think from what you write it is unclear why they should get back to you. You said "There's an error", they acted upon it.  If you want to know what their plans are, I think it is on you to ask.

Comment: I think it is quite clear from my mail and asking them for an update on the status of the publication.  A lot of time and hardwork is put into a paper and is not subject to disposal just like that without providing information about future actions.

Comment: Have you fixed the mistake by now? Otherwise, there seems no hurry, unless you intend to submit the erroneous paper to another journal.

Comment: What makes you think I would send the erroneous paper to another journal? I will remove the part with the error. My paper with the remaining results still holds value after that.

Comment: Why not stick with the same journal, but update your submission by removing the erroneous part?

Comment: I had proposed that option too in the first mail. But no reply.

Comment: You can't submit it elsewhere unless you get the copyright back. If they have otherwise published it (print, say), then that is probably impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question (or series of questions) for the editor. You can ask what they intend to do beyond taking down the online version. Ask if you can provide a correction (assuming that is possible). Ask if there is anything else you can do.

And an email "yesterday" won't get a response for a while.

But look for some mutually acceptable outcome.

I don't think the copyright transfer has any bearing on this, actually, other than that they have the responsibility now.

Comment: Actually I messaged the secretary again almost a month after the paper was taken down and not getting any reply after informing the error.

Comment: I think you've done the right thing, but, but don't be too optimistic about replies. You expected something more after the first communication, but it is possible that they thought taking it down was enough, unless you specifically asked for more of a response. Hopefully you will get something from the secretary soon-ish.